# Finding Laplace Transform of $(t-4)h(t-4)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Find the Laplace Transform of $(t-4)h(t-4)$, where

$$h(t) = \begin{cases}
1, & t > 0 \\
0, & t < 0\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

I am thinking about using the shifting theorem here. But coud not get to the core of it. Are there multiple ways to do this ?

Comment: Just use the definition of the laplace transform and it should be easy.

Comment: @dustin what should i replace $h(t-4)$ with .if i use definition

Comment: You want to use f(t-d)h(t-d) has transform $e^{-ds}F(s)$ where f(t) transforms to F(s). So, what are f(t) and F(s)? Note that f(t) and f(t)h(t) are essentially the same function for t>0.

Comment: @Paul i was thinking on these lines ,but can you elaborate more ? why  f(t) and f(t)h(t) are essentially the same function

Comment: We only consider f(t) for $t\ge 0$ so f(t) and f(t)h(t) are exactly the same thing. Then f(t)h(t) has transform F(s). If you can identify f(t), then you can look up F(s) and then write down $e^{-ds}F(s)$ for an appropriate d value.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform is
$$
\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt
$$
Since you have a shifted unit step, the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty (t-4)h(t-4)e^{-st}dt=\int_0^4 0\cdot(t-4)e^{-st}dt+\int_4^\infty 1\cdot(t-4)e^{-st}dt=\int_4^\infty (t-4)e^{-st}dt
$$
Can you integrate this?

Comment: yes sure .thanks

Comment: @godonichia you don't need to worry about all the shifting theorems if you just plug in and integrate.

Comment: i asked because i did lot of questions based on them ,